# Is it possible to se a macro in .viemurc for ViEmu?

Tags: visual-studio, macros, viemu

I am using the ViEmu plugin for VS2008.

I was wondering if there is a way to set a macro in the .viemurc file, so I don't have to redo it every time I start up VS.

I know that it can be done in regular Vim via:

```
:let @s="0ftwwy$bp"
```

This will set a macro on register 's' for example.

Doing the same in .viemurc so far just got me an error message.

Comment: Well, it just lets me know that it couldn't process the line of the .viemurc file on which I have the :let ... statement.

If I on the other hand directly type :let @s="0ftwwy$bp" inside VS, it says "Unknown command", so I guess ":let" is not understood by ViEmu.

Answer (score 0):

Someone just answered the same question [here](http://www.viemu.com/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=3419#p3419).

Right now ViEmu doesn't support setting macros in the .viemurc.

Unfortunately multi-key mappings are not supported yet either.